# C++ function modifiers in header or in source? Quick reference

Tags: c++, function

It is common to declare a function (e.g. in a header) and then later define it (e.g. in a source file).

Whenever I have to apply a modifier (e.g. static, inline, const, extern, default arguments, etc) to a function, I can never remember whether it should go in the declaration, the definition, or both.

For example, from what I can tell, arguments can be `const` in *either or both* the declaration and definition, functions must be `const` in *both* the declaration and definition, functions must be `static` *only* in the declaration, and so on.

**Can you provide a quick reference list of all the possible function modifiers and whether they should be assigned in the declaration, the definition, or both?** Many of the individual cases seem to have been asked on this site before, so it would be nice to pool those answers. **Alternatively, are there any rules of thumb for figuring out where to apply modifiers?**

Comment: If I remember correctly, anything and everything that is *part of the function signature* goes in both the files.

Comment: As far as const goes, it has to be in both the declaration and definition or else it is considered a different overload. The same does not go for the inline modifier. You can have a declaration and definition in the same header file and only the definition will have to have inline keyword.

Comment: @tobi303 I'm afraid you are wrong. Argument `const` is exempt from function signatures, and they should not be const at declaration. The reason is that, if you later decide to change their `const`-qualification in the definition (e.g. to reuse it as a loop counter), you don't have to update the header, and so your clients (including yourself) don't have to recompile all of their files that `#include` it. `const` of a referent _does_ matter, but that's not related to the argument (i.e. local variable) itself.

Comment: @underscore_d I just [checked it](http://ideone.com/4MXTSL) and I am afraid you are right...actually I am a bit confused, as for [reference parameters the constness seems to matter](http://ideone.com/n5kmnr)

Comment: @underscore_d sry, I overlooked your last sentence before. If it didnt matter for references it would really have been a shock for me, and for non reference parameters I can understand, that it really does not matter...I am still a bit confused, but thats just part of the process of learning c++ ;)

Comment: Confusion is the norm! Yeah, the key difference is: the `const` that _does_ matter is a property of the referred object, not the argument itself. Since reference variables don't have a concept of `const` (as they _are_ the referent and can't be reseated), this is best demonstrated with pointers, i.e. `SomeObject const *aPtr` is signature-wise equivalent to - and better than! - `SomeObject const *const aPtr`.

Answer (score 0):

A possible rule of thumb for when you have a declaration in the header and a definition in a source file would be -> if you want the modifier to affect every source that uses the function then put it into the header. And mostly you want to affect all the source files.

**However**, there really isn't a general rule. You have to understand what each modifier does and then you know exactly why it is written in a header file or in a source file or in both.

Comment: No, there are specific rules for different aspects of functions regarding where they can/must be declared, and what the effects are. It's rarely just a personal choice like you're implying here.